# WebAPI self-host 503 error (HttpSelfHostConfiguration setted HttpSelfHostConfiguration)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a window service using self-hosted WebAPI.
HttpSelfHostConfiguration.HostNameComparisonMode set HostNameComparisonMode.Exact for hostname strong match.

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(uri);
config.HttpSelfHostConfiguration = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
this._server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
_server.OpenAsync().Wait();
```

And URL reservation for the specified URL namespace for the domain.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:443/ user=EVERYONE
```

To bind an SSL certificate to a port number.

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=xxxxxxxxxxx appid={xxxxxxxxx}
```

But Result appear HTTP 503 error.
I don't know state.

Comment: What account are you running the service under?

Comment: Account is Local System.

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar problem. Problem in my case was duplicate urlacl for my URL.

```
netsh http show urlacl
...
http://+:80/api 
http://127.0.0.1:80/api (or any IP)
```

Remove any possible duplicate urlacl for your program.

Comment: Incredible.  I would love to know why it behaves this way.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for pointing this out. This is so deceiving because the SelfHost service, or something, will accept port connections still so it appears configured correctly. Deleting all the entries with the same port match and then recreating it fixed my issue.